# Example of two open disjoint dense subset of a set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Example of two open disjoint dense subset of a set
They are some dense disjoint subsets of sets but I can't think of two open ones.

Comment: Why are you looking for this? Is it an exercise from your book? Did you think of it yourself?

Comment: An exercise from the book Dynamical system and Chaos theory by Behrooz Raisi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a pair of subsets cannot exist. To see this, let us assume that $C_1,C_2\subset X$ be both open, disjoint and dense in $X$. Then $C_1\subset X-C_2$. But $X-C_2$ is a closed set. Thus, $\overline{C_1}=X\subset X-C_2$ which is absurd unless $C_2=\phi=X=C_1$

Comment: +1. Another way to see this: If $C_1$ is dense and $C_2$ is open and not empty, then $C_1\cap C_2$ is not empty because $C_1$ is dense. So $C_2$ is empty. But $C_2$ is also dense, so the whole space is empty.